# How to Support Multiple Languages in the App , Without Depending on the Phone's Current Language

Tags: android

hey mates i am Trying to Use other Languages in my App (Persian), and i want it to be Both phone Device Dependant and and Not being Dependant (Phone be English but app be Persian), So if i simply Use R.String.myOtherLang, the App's Out put is some meaningless Number like it Doesnt recognize the language, if i Use getResources().getString(R.String.myOtherLang) , it returns Could not find the Resource Exception if the App's Language be not same (Using values-fa), But when i Enter the Text in Persian directly to the XML layout file, it works Fine, Is there any Way i can Get the language Depenancy from The Phone to User Choice?

Comment: `getResources().getString(R.String.myOtherLang)`: no... you put a file named `strings.xml` in `values-en` and in `values-fa` (or `values-ir`?). Then in code you set the locale to en or fa (ir?) and finally apply by restarting the activity. Then it's `getResources().getString(R.String.myString)` (myString has the **same name** in both strings files)

Comment: nah -fa is the right one,and dude as i mentioned i have a values-fa folder with strings.xml inside it, but i can use it just when phone's language is set to persian and i dont want to change the phone's language , i just want to change app's language, is it possible?

Comment: Maybe you didn't read when I said you have to **change the locale in code**, then **restart the activity**?

Comment: no actually i didnt, and yep that worked, put it as answer if you will , thanks

Comment: i think that i just needed to know it is possible since i already done them, but had problem with tetings :P

Comment: OK, posted as an answer, so that you can accept it an remove it from the Unanswered Queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, you need to you put a file named `strings.xml` in both `values-en` and in `values-fa`.

Then in code you can set the locale to **en** or **fa**, respectively and finally apply by restarting the activity (simply finish it before restarting it).

Then it's: `getResources().getString(R.String.myString)` (note that `myString` has to have the same name in both the strings files)